# can't feed images to feed_dict

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

i am trying to feed the neural network using feed_dict but this produces this error "**unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'**"

the input of the feed dict is images which is a list of images with shape (width,height,channels) and steer which is a 2d array

```
def batch_gen(data_dir, image_paths, steering_angles, batch_size, 
    is_training):
    index = np.random.permutation(image_paths.shape[0])
    for center, left, right in image_paths[index]:
       center = center
       left = left
       right = right
       break
    steering_angle = steering_angles[index]
    # argumentation
    if is_training and np.random.rand() < 0.6:
        image, steering_angle = augument(data_dir, center, left, right, 
         steering_angle)
    else:
        image = load_image(data_dir, center) 
            # add the image and steering angle to the batch
    images = preprocess(image)
    steers = steering_angle
    return images,steers
```

#

with tf.Session() as sess:

# Run the initializer
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for step in range(1, num_steps+1):
            # Run optimization op (backprop)
        images, steer = batch_gen(data_dir, X_train, y_train, 5, True)
        print(images.shape)
        sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={images, steer})

so what does unhashable means and how do i solve this problem

Comment: still the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

feed_dict is a dictionary (key-value pair).

```
e.g. feed_dict={  x: images, y: steer }
```

x & y are the keys which needs to be of hashable type. In your case, you're passing images as the dictionary key directly which is creating the unhashable type error.

x & y (for your network the names maybe different) are usually the tf.placeholder in your network.

e.g.

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.placeholder("float", None)
y = tf.placeholder("float", None)
z = x * y

with tf.Session() as session:
    result = session.run(z, feed_dict={x: [1, 2, 3], y: [2,4,6]})
    print(result)
```